# Adding & Removing A View Overlay in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, viewcontroller

Following from this question: [Loading Screen from any Class in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682646/loading-screen-from-any-class-in-swift)

**Issue**: The loading overlay view will display but will not hide when hideOverlayView() is called. Oddly however, the overlay disappears after some time (15 to 30 seconds after it appears)

**Code**: Contained in *FirstController.swift*

```
public class LoadingOverlay{

var overlayView = UIView()
var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

class var shared: LoadingOverlay {
    struct Static {
        static let instance: LoadingOverlay = LoadingOverlay()
    }
    return Static.instance
}

public func showOverlay() {
    if  let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate,
        let window = appDelegate.window {
            overlayView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)
            overlayView.center = CGPointMake(window.frame.width / 2.0, window.frame.height / 2.0)
            overlayView.backgroundColor = MyGlobalVariables.UICOLORGREEN
            overlayView.clipsToBounds = true
            overlayView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

            activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
            activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .WhiteLarge
            activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(overlayView.bounds.width / 2, overlayView.bounds.height / 2)

            overlayView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
            window.addSubview(overlayView)

            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }
}

public func hideOverlayView() {
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    overlayView.removeFromSuperview()
}
}
```

And called in functions in *DataManager.swift* as:

```
LoadingOverlay.shared.showOverlay()
```

**Solution:**

I was calling on a background thread. As per the answers below, call as:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { // This makes the code run on the main thread
  LoadingOverlay.shared.hideOverlayView()          
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Swift 2**

Are you calling `hideOverlayView()` from a background thread? If you are, you should make sure it runs on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { // This makes the code run on the main thread
  LoadingOverlay.shared.hideOverlayView()          
})
```

**Swift 3+**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  LoadingOverlay.shared.hideOverlayView()
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you!